# How to get the list of latest chats that I have in telegram

Tags: bots, telegram, telethon

I want to write a program that gets the list of the latest chats that I had in telegram and their not in my contacts. I tried telethon but I couldn't do it for the users that are not in my contacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "latest chats" you refer to "recent open conversations with other users, groups, or channels you've joined", then you're looking for [`client.iter_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs):

```py
# Print all dialog IDs and the title, nicely formatted
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    print('{:>14}: {}'.format(dialog.id, dialog.title))
```